# ANYLOGIC: how to make a specific pool work on an agent if a condition is met?

Tags: variables, parameters, anylogic, agent

I need help with AnyLogic.

At the "exit" of my Source Block, I need that my agent get assigned a number from 1 to 24.
Then, during the process, in the Service Block, I would like that for each number, a specific pool works.

In other word, I would like that at the beginning of the process, my agent has a number assigned, then during the process this number decide which team of resource (from the resource pool) work with it.

I hope it is clear.

Thank you all

I tried to create a parameter on my agent that assign a random number. I do not know if it is correct and how I could assign a particolar resource pool at a number in the service block.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Suggest you do all the step-by-step tutorials first, they cover this and many other basic concepts of AnyLogic modelling: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html . Do the "Process modelling" ones first as they include how to give agents individual characteristics that are then applied in the flow chart :)

Comment: (also, more meta: SOF is not the place to ask "how do I" questions, check this guide for AnyLogic newcomers: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community )

Comment: @Benjamin thank you! I thought I was more specific. Maybe I did an error in formulating the answer. What I meant is that I created a variable called "Spec" that as initial value has a random number assignation from 1 to 24. Now, for each patient who enters my process, I want the seize block to seize the resource pool that match the resource to be called for each specific number. Can you help me with this? Or could you tell me where to put this question? 
Thank you

Comment: Why not assign a random pool as a variable of your agents at start? Then, the Seize block can simply seize from the pool of the agent trying to seize. Save yourself some work :)

Comment: @Benjamin I do not have clear how to assign a resource pool as a variable of my agent at start. do you have any suggestion of where can I find this information? Thank you :)